# Extending functionality of Element and ElementTree

Tags: python, xml.etree

I would like to extend the functionality of `Element` and `ElementTree` classes from `xml.etree` and use them with `xml.etree.ElementTree.parse()`.

After a few tries, I've managed to create a solution for that problem, but I would like to know if there is a better solution or if this one has any hidden dangers.

**FooElementTree.py**

```
import xml.etree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree

class FooElement(Element):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<FooElement %s at 0x%x>" % (repr(self.tag), id(self))

class FooElementTree(ElementTree):
    pass

xml.etree.ElementTree.Element = FooElement
xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree = FooElementTree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse
```

**Usage:**

```
>>> import FooElementTree
>>> e = FooElementTree.parse('xml.cfg')
>>> e
<FooElementTree.FooElementTree object at 0x023AB650>
>>> r = e.getroot()
>>> r
<FooElement 'configuration' at 0x23c5470>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way, hot patching works. But be aware, that the patch has to be applied before any other Module (or Submodule) is imported, that uses ElementTree, too.

Comment: Is this still a valid solution for python3?